# How do I get a regular expression to recognize non-ASCII characters as letters?

Tags: python, regex, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I'm extracting information from a webpage in Swedish. This page is using characters like: öäå.

My problem is that when I print the information the öäå are gone.

I'm extracting the information using Beautiful Soup. I think that the problem is that I do a bunch of regular expressions on the strings that I extract, e.g. `location = re.sub(r'([^\w])+', '', location)` to remove everything except for the letters. Before this I guess that Beautiful Soup encoded the strings so that the öäå became something like /x02/, a hex value.

So if I'm correct, then the regexes are removing the öäå, right, I mean the only thing that should be left of the hex char is x after the regex, but there are no x instead of öäå on my page, so this little theory is maybe not correct? Anyway, if it's right or wrong, how do you solve this? When I later print the extracted information to my webpage i use self.response.out.write() in google app engine (don't know if that help in solving the problem)

EDIT: The encoding on the Swedish site is utf-8 and the encoding on my site is also utf-8. 
EDIT2: You can use ISO-8859-10 for Swedish, but according to google chrome the encoding is Unicode(utf-8) on this specific site

Comment: I think the whole point of using `BeautifulSoup` is not to use regex.

Comment: Please have a read at http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: This is likely an encoding issue (UTF-8 vs ISO-8859-x with x being whatever codepage is used for Swedish) but without more detail about the encodings being used it's hard to tell.

Comment: @JimGarrison Not this time. It's basically what @jsbueno thought -- you need to work in `unicode` and not on encoded text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Always work in unicode** and only convert to an encoded representation when necessary.

For this particular situation, you also need to use the [`re.U`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.U) flag so `\w` matches unicode letters:

```
#coding: utf-8

import re

location = "öäå".decode('utf-8')
location = re.sub(r'([^\w])+', '', location, flags=re.U)

print location # prints öäå
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could dump the strings before and after each step.

Check your value of `re.UNICODE` first, see [this](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.UNICODE)