# Regexp to match chords, issue with national accents

Tags: python, regex

I am dealing with this problem. I have `*.txt` file containing tens of songs. Each song might consist of

- name
- lines with chords
- lines with lyrics
- blank lines

I'm writing Python script, which reads the file by lines. I need to recognise the lines with chords. For that purpose I have decided to use regular expressions, since it looks like playful but strong tool for such tasks. I am new to regexp, I've done this [tutorial](http://regexone.com/lesson/) (which I am rather fond of). I have written something like this

```
\b ?\(?([AC-Hac-h]{1})(#|##|b|bb)?(is|mi|maj|sus)?\d?[ \n(/\(\))?]
```

I am not very happy with that, since it does not do the job properly. One of the problems is that the language of the songs uses a lot of accents. The second one: the chords might come in pairs - e.g. C(D), h/e. You can see my approach [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cb%20%3F%5C%28%3F%28%5BAC-Hac-h%5D%7B1%7D%29%28%23%7C%23%23%7Cb%7Cbb%29%3F%28is%7Cmi%7Cmaj%7Csus%29%3F%5Cd%3F%5B%20%5Cn%28%2F%5C%28%5C%29%29%3F%5D&input=C%23%0AC%23maj7%0AC%20C%20%0A%0A%20C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20%20C7%20F%20%20%20%20%20d%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G%20%20G7%0APros%C3%ADme%20T%C4%9B%2C%20dej%20n%C3%A1m%2C%20Pane%20s%C3%ADlu%2C%20chceme%20za%C4%8D%C3%ADt%20podle%20slov%20Tv%C3%BDch%20%C5%BE%C3%ADt.%0A%20C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20C7%20%20%20%20%20%20%20F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G%20%20%20%20%20%20C%20%20G%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%2F%3AV%C4%9B%C5%99%C3%ADme%20%C5%BEe%2C%20jednou%20budem%20v%C2%A0m%C3%ADru%20spole%C4%8Dn%C4%9B%20u%20Tv%C3%A9ho%20stolu%20v%C3%ADno%20p%C3%ADt%3A.%2F%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20D%28E%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20A%28H%29%0A%20Pri%C5%A1li%20sme%20%C5%A4a%20vz%C3%BDva%C5%A5%2C%20pri%C5%A1li%20sme%20sa%20skl%C3%A1%C5%88a%C5%A5%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20h%2Fcis%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G%28A%29%0Apri%C5%A1li%20sme%20Ti%20vyzna%C5%A5%3A%20%E2%80%9ESi%20n%C3%A1%C5%A1%20Boh%E2%80%9C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20D%28E%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20A%28H%29%0ASi%20dokonal%C3%A1%20l%C3%A1ska%2C%20dokonale%20sv%C3%A4t%C3%BD%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20h%28cis%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20G%28A%29).

**Note**
For better readability in final script I would split the regexp into more variables and those then add together.

**Edit**

After rereading my question I thought, that my goal might not be clear enough. I would like to much different types of chords for instance:

```
C, C#, Cis, c#, Cmaj, Cmi, Csus, C7, C#7, Db, Dbsus
```

Also sometimes there might be (no more than two) chord next to each other such as this: `C7/D7, Cmi(a)`. The best solution would be to catch those "pairs" together in one that is match `C7/D7` not `C7` and `D7`. I think, that with this additional condition it might be a bit robust, but if it would be unnecessarily difficult I might go with the (I assume) easier version (meaning: matching `C7` and `D7` instead of `C7/D7`) and deal with this later separately.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165102/how-do-i-get-a-regular-expression-to-recognize-non-ascii-characters-as-letters) might provide the solution.

Comment: Instead of throwing a regex at the whole file and hoping it works, use that prior knowledge of chord lines being separate from lyric lines to classify lines as chord-or-not-chord.  Then once you have them separated out, tokenizing is quite easy.

Comment: @roippi The structure is not precisely as the list items are above. When I say "might" that means there may be several lines of e.g. only lyrics. So , I don't know which line is which. My bad I did not emphasize that.

Comment: That doesn't stop you from applying a heuristic to figure it out. You could e.g.  Look at letter frequency, word length, symbol inclusion (lines with accents are lyric lines), etc.  There are lots of ways to do it.

Comment: @roippi I have thought about it, but it still seems to me as much more difficult approach. I have figured out how to change encoding, so that the regexp works properly. Now I have problems with writing it into a file(encoding issue).

Comment: So using Python `codecs` module I have been successful. I open the file with different encoding(which I know), that is `with codecs.open( path_to_file, 'r', encoding='1250') as f:` and then this regexp `re.match( re, string, re.U='1250')` works.

Comment: Does that mean you don't have any problem with this now? If so, you might answer your own question.

Comment: @Jerry Well, not really, since my regexp still catches words, e.g. `a=Ami`, but `a` is also word in Czech, `a=and`. I think I won't press using regexp and making it more robust. I was thinking of answering my question, but I would like to provide it in its fullness, and since it is still not working properly I can't do that.

Comment: It might help if you could provide an example of what the unprocessed text data looks like.

Comment: @bluebaby Either I do not understand you or you missed the link in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your Python script reads the text file line by line and you want to find out with a regular expression if the current line is a line with chords or with other information.

Perhaps it is enough to apply the regular expression `^[\t #()/\dAC-Hac-jmsu]+$` on each line. If the regular expression does not return a match, the line contains characters not being allowed in a line with chords. Perhaps this simple regular expression using only a single character class definition is enough.

But it could be that a line with a name or lyrics matches also the expression above. For your example this is not the case, but it could be. In such a case I would suggest to use first the function `strip()` on every line to remove spaces and tabs from begin and end of every line. And then apply the following regular expression

`^(?:[#()/\dAC-Hac-jmsu]{1,6}[\t ]+?)*[#()/\dAC-Hac-jmsu]{1,6}$`

The difference is that now each string not containing a space or tab character must have a length between 1 to 6. Longer strings are not allowed. With this additional rule it could be that there are no false positive anymore on detection of lines with chords.

The problems for the chords line detection rule are definitely the letters as a name or a lyric text consisting only of the letters allowed for chords could match too. A solution would be to create a list of strings consisting only of letters which are allowed for chords and using them in an OR expression. That would avoid most likely a false positive by a name or lyric string. With the complete list of chord strings it is most likely also possible to define the rule shorter without the need to list all chord strings in an OR expression.